# Array (table row) push spreadsheet formula?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm seeking for a formula (set of formulas) to execute a kind of array push on spreadsheet.

[Sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tzmBHcngkHxyhBl2qQIbBBu2sJfWheqOX16MN47LOAM/edit?usp=sharing)

If we have a column `D` of values and cell `B1` to let user enter a new value. There should be a formula (very eager to avoid scripting) which checks if the value already exists on the list and if not -- pushes the new value at the end of column `D` and keep other values. If the user enter new value to `B1` then again it's pushed to the end.

Comment: A check is a work for a formula. Adding new value is a script or VBA.

Comment: Thank you, Max for the first answer! I was thinking about utilizing some array but not sure how to do this without getting a reverse reference error. I mean for example: to use another column as an array of values from `D:D` then each other row (cell below) in `D` would check if this array already has new value and if not then the cell would take a new value. But again there is a problem with double reference.

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets

You may achieve a similar result with 3 lists:

- list A (Master). Is a predefined,
- list B (User input). A column, where a user may type any values to populate
- list A + B. The list with the formula:

`=QUERY(UNIQUE({A2:A;E2:E}),"select * where Col1 <> ''")`

`A2:A` is a list A,
`E2:E` is a list B

[image]

**Restriction.** A user has to put new values in the next cells to save all previous values. If all the user values are entered in a cell (i.e. cell F1), then you need a script to populate list B, and `onEdit` trigger.